# Anyone experienced the warning about Google colaboratory:You are connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilizing the GPU

Tags: cloud, gpu, google-colaboratory

This warning has been going on for three weeks now. I would like to know this solution. [this warning comes out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZSxK.png)

Comment: Maybe it means that you did not use a GPU-accelerated Python library in your code? Such as TensorFlow, Pytorch, cuPy and so on.
For details please check :
https://towardsdatascience.com/python-performance-and-gpus-1be860ffd58d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it means your work isn't using the GPU. GPU and TPU runtimes are valued more than the "None" runtime. Colab only allows for two GPU runtime sessions at a time. None allows for approximatley five.

Also they only allow for twelve hours total use, and each session will be cumulative.

If you don't need or don't know if you need GPU, I would suggest the None runtime. Colab is lenient on timeouts and amount of sessions if the runtime is None.

---

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html

> **I saw a message saying my GPU is not being utilized. What should I do?**
>
> Colab offers optional accelerated compute environments, including GPU and TPU. Executing code in a GPU or TPU runtime does not automatically mean that the GPU or TPU is being utilized. To avoid hitting your GPU usage limits, we recommend switching to a standard runtime if you are not utilizing the GPU. Choose Runtime > Change Runtime Type and set Hardware Accelerator to None.
>
> For examples of how to utilize GPU and TPU runtimes in Colab, see the Tensorflow With GPU and TPUs In Colab example notebooks.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.
I used to use them when I didn't need a GPU or TPU, so I choose 'NONE' when I don't need them.

Comment: I usually encounter this warning when I'm working with `tensorflow`. However, when I choose `None` as runtime, it leads to a lower training rate significantly (~8x slower).

Answer (score 0):

To set the runtime to None from  Colab

Runtime> Change Runtime Type> Hardware Accelerator [None]