# i have a question about using GPU in Colab

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

Hi Im using Colab for my project

And I have a problem about using GPU in Colab.

Although I Change My Runtime Type to 'GPU'

However, I keep getting a pop-up saying'I am connected to the GPU runtime but I am not using the GPU'.

For reference, I got a message like this because it was less than 10 minutes after I started learning. Is there a need for extra code to use the GPU?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anyone experienced the warning about Google colaboratory:You are connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilizing the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360422/anyone-experienced-the-warning-about-google-colaboratoryyou-are-connected-to-a)

Comment: No more code required to use GPU. This message indicates that the user is connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilizing the GPU and so a less costly CPU runtime would be more suitable. Thanks!

Comment: Reminds me of [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520206/cant-use-whole-gpu-in-google-colab). I'm not familiar with Tensorflow, but I guess you need to put your data to GPU to use this exact device (as it is done in PyTorch, like tensor.to(device)).